# Group generated by groups.

Tags: group-theory

Given a group $G$ is a external product denoted by $G = \displaystyle \prod_{ i = 0 }^n G_i $ and $H_i$ be the image of the inclusion homomorphism $f_i : G_i → G$, show that $G = ⟨H_1,...,H_n⟩$.

I have no clue how to deal with the generator which is not element but group. Since it is generator set, each $H$ should be elements of $G$, but $G$ is an external product so that its elements are tuples of length n.
 What is meant by $G = ⟨H_1,...,H_n⟩$ ?

Also as H is an elements of inclusion mapping, is this true that $G = ⟨G_1,...,G_n⟩$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be an arbitrary group and let $A \subset G$. Then we define $\langle A \rangle$ as the intersection of all subgroups $H \subset G$ that contain $A$. Thus $\langle A \rangle$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ that contains $A$. If $A = \lbrace a_1, \dots, a_n \rbrace$ is finite, we write $\langle a_1, \dots, a_n \rangle$ instead of $\langle \lbrace a_1, \dots, a_n \rbrace \rangle$. In your case we take several sets (even groups). Just think of the set generated by all the elements that belong to $H_1 \cup \dots \cup H_n$. Thus your generating set contains all elements of the form $(1, \dots, 1, g_i, 1, \dots, 1)$, where $g_i \in G_i$. Do you now see why you will get the entire group?

No, that is not true. That is because the $G_i$ are not subsets of $G$. It works intuitively when you embed the $G_i$, but that is what the $H_i$ are.